# Make ICMP exempt from IPSec protection

Tags: ipsec, icmp

I'm reading a reference book on Microsoft DirectAccess.  It contains the quote:

> To use Ping as a troubleshooting tool, ensure that Internet Control
>   Message Protocol (ICMP) is exempt from IPSec protection between the
>   DirectAccess client and the remote endpoint of the IPSec connection.

How do I do this?  (Assuming the client PC is running Windows 7.)  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's under the Windows Firewall advanced settings.  Open Windows Firewall with Advanced Security, then click on Properties in the Actions pane.  Switch to the IPsec Settings tab.  Set Exempt ICMP from IPsec to Yes.  That's it!